# How to recursively query a table of items that are linked to each other?

Tags: postgresql

I have a system which stores items, and can receive new items which replace existing items. Each item has its own unique ID, and when an item is received that replaces a previous item, we have a reference to the item that it replaces.

This results in

- Items that have never received an update (their ID is not present in `referenced_item_id`)
- Items that have been updated 1 or more times (this creates a list of updates)

#### item

```
id Message
-- -------
1  Original item
2  This replaces item #1
3  Standalone item
4  This replaces item #2
```

#### item_reference

```
item_id referenced_item_id
------- ------------------
2       1
4       2
```

If I have the ID `1`, how can I query the tables recursively so that I can get item `4`?

Another useful query would be, given an ID, how can I get all related items?

NOTE: I am open to improvements on how the data is stored, however it is stored in this manner as it is adhering to an existing specification. Ideally, I would like to keep this format for simplicity’s sake.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a solution thanks to this video, https://youtu.be/QNfnuK-1YYY?t=35.

The following query will return the latest version of an item, given an id.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE item_updates AS (
  select
    id,
    message
  FROM
    item 
  WHERE
    id = 1
  UNION
    select
      i.id,
      i.message
    FROM
      item_updates prev_item 
    join item_reference on item_reference.referenced_item_id = prev_item.id
    join item i on i.id = item_reference.item_id
) 
select 
  * 
from 
  item_updates
order by 
  id desc
limit 
  1
;
```

If you remove the limit from the final select then you can get all of the update versions given an id -

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE item_updates AS (
    select
      id,
      message
    FROM
      item 
    WHERE
      id = 1
    UNION
      select
        i.id,
        i.message
      FROM
        item_updates prev_item 
      join item_reference on item_reference.referenced_item_id = prev_item.id
      join item i on i.id = item_reference.item_id
  ) 
 select * from item_updates;
```

```
1   Original item
2   This replaces item 1
4   This replaces item 2
```

I am not sure if this is the most performant way of doing it, but it works.